# Disable Gmail tablet view on browser?

Tags: gmail, chrome-for-android, tablet

Here's how the layout of gmail.com in Chrome looks on a tablet:

(note this is an old pic I just Googled but layout is simlar)

[image]

How can I disable this so that it doesn't show subjects and messages side by side? I want it to be like mobile phone view where the whole screen only shows subjects or message at a time (not side by side).